# How to find json object inside the list of jsons?

Tags: python, json

Here I want to find the matching json object from the json file(sample below). The provided json object which needs to be matched inside the `.json` file will also have same format.
After the json object gets matched to one of them, then i want to return the previous object of that matched json object.

What is the best and **fastest** way to perform this with python ?

my_json_file.json

```
{
    "all_data": [
        {
          "key":"value",
          "key2": {
            "key": "val"
           }
        },
        {
          "key":"value",
          "key2": {
            "key": "val"
           }
        },
        {
          "key":"value",
          "key2": {
            "key": "val"
           }
        },
    ]
}
```

get_value.py

```
with open('my_json.json') as file:
   file_data = json.load(file)
   if some_json in file_data:
       # return previous json
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enumerate` to iterate over `file_data['all_data']`:

```py
def fct(file_path, some_json_obj):
    with open(file_path) as file:
        file_data = json.load(file)
        for i, obj in enumerate(file_data['all_data']):
            if obj == some_json_obj: # some_json_obj will have same format as i
                if i == 0:
                    print("First object match!")
                    return None
                else:
                    print(f"Matched object #{i}, returning #{i-1}")
                    return file_data['all_data'][i-1]
        print("No match!")
        return None
```

Comment: is this the right way to compare `obj == some_json_obj` ?

Comment: `obj == some_json_obj` will return True if `obj` and `some_json_obj` have the same keys and values, False otherwise.

Comment: Do you think this is the fastest possible way for my requirement or there can be other approaches as well since i want this function to perform fast as much as possible

Comment: I don't see potential for improvement in this case

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you looking for but your code looks right to me

```py
import json
FILENAME="my_json"
DATA_FIELD_NAME="all_data"
lost_found={}
def find(filename=FILENAME,data_field_name=DATA_FIELD_NAME,lost_object=lost_found,default=None):
    with open("{filename}.json".format(filename=filename)) as raw_file:
        json_file = json.load(raw_file)
        data = json_file[data_field_name]
        data_length=len(data)
        # if the data_length less than 1 no prev exist
        if data_length < 1:
            raise Exception("No data")
        else:
            previous_data_element = data[0]
            result=default
            for data_element in data:
                if data_element == lost_found:
                    result= previous_data_element
                    break
                previous_data_element= data_element
            return result
```